# Adding a column to a PySpark dataframe contans standard deviations of a column based on the grouping on two another columns

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, standard-deviation

Suppose that we have a csv file which has been imported as a dataframe in PysPark as follows

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("file path and name.csv", inferSchema = True, header = True)
df.show()

output

+-----+----+----+
|lable|year|val |
+-----+----+----+
|    A|2003| 5.0|
|    A|2003| 6.0|
|    A|2003| 3.0|
|    A|2004|null|
|    B|2000| 2.0|
|    B|2000|null|
|    B|2009| 1.0|
|    B|2000| 6.0|
|    B|2009| 6.0|
+-----+----+----+
```

Now, we want to add another column to `df` which contains the standard deviation of `val` based on the grouping on two columns `lable` and `year`. So, the output must be as follows:

```
+-----+----+----+-----+
|lable|year|val | std |
+-----+----+----+-----+
|    A|2003| 5.0| 1.53|
|    A|2003| 6.0| 1.53|
|    A|2003| 3.0| 1.53|
|    A|2004|null| null|
|    B|2000| 2.0| 2.83|
|    B|2000|null| 2.83|
|    B|2009| 1.0| 3.54|
|    B|2000| 6.0| 2.83|
|    B|2009| 6.0| 3.54|
+-----+----+----+-----+
```

I have the following codes which works for a small dataframe but it does not work for a very large dataframe (with about 40 million rows) which I am working with now.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f    
a = df.groupby('lable','year').agg(f.round(f.stddev("val"),2).alias('std'))
df = df.join(a, on = ['lable', 'year'], how = 'inner')
```

I get `Py4JJavaError Traceback (most recent call last)` error after running on my large dataframe.

Does anyone knows any alternative way? I hope your way works on my dataset.

I am using `python3.7.1`, `pyspark2.4`, and `jupyter4.4.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join on dataframe causes a lot of data shuffle between executors. In your case, you can do without the join.
Use a window specification to partition data by 'lable' and 'year' and aggregate on the window.

```
from pyspark.sql.window import *

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('lable','year')\
                   .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df = df.withColumn("std", f.round(f.stddev("val").over(windowSpec), 2))
```

Comment: Done. Could you please look at my other question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54192113/how-to-add-a-column-to-a-pyspark-dataframe-which-contains-the-nth-quantile-of-an?noredirect=1#comment95251427_54192113. You might have some answer.